# form validation with red error messages not working (php, ajax, jquery, and mysql)

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Well, brothers, I'm having a problem with the appearance of notices concerning the form validation. I associate the problem to a few issues on the php code like arrays defined by the variables $errors and $data. I really didn't understand the usage of them. Or maybe it's related to somewhere in the jQuery code.
These codes were based on a website tutorial I've found on the internet. Also, I have no experience in the Ajax and jQuery arenas. Maybe you can solve this simple issue. I even appended the screen captures of the sign up page along with the next page which processes the php connection with database.

[This is the sign up page called join_form.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r93rM.png)

[This is the processing page called register2.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIarG.png)

This is html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>
    This is the form page
  </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <br>
      <br>
      <img src="images/quintz.png" width="156" height="44" alt=""/>
      <br>
      <br>
      Register now
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id="bugado">
        <form id="ajax_form" method="post" action="register2.php">
          <div id="usertype-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="usertype">
              You're a 
              </label>

              <select name="usertype" class="form-control">
                <option value="native speaker">
                  Native speaker
                </option>
                <option value="non-native speaker">
                  Non-native speaker
                </option>
              </select>
              <br>
              <!-- errors will go here -->
              </div>
              <div id="username-group" class="form-group">
                <label for="username">
                  Create username: 
                </label>

                <input name="username" type="text" maxlength="30" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                <br>
              </div>
              <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
                <label for="email">
                  Email: 
                </label>

                <input name="email" type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                <br>
                <!-- errors will go here -->
              </div>
              <div id="password-group" class="form-group">
                <label for="password">
                  Create password: 
                </label>

                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <br>
              </div>
              <label>
                Confirm password: 
              </label>

              <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password again">
              <br>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                Submit
              </button>
              <span class="fa fa-arrow-right">
              </span>
              <br>
              <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
              </form>
              </div>
          </center>
      </body>
</html>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('#ajax_form').submit(function(event) {

        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class
        $('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text

        // get the form data
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData = {
            'usertype'               : $('select[name="usertype"]').val(),
            'username'              : $('input[name="username"]').val(),
            'email'             : $('input[name="email"]').val(),
            'password'  : $('input[name="password"]').val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : $(form).attr('action'), // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data); 

                // here we will handle errors and validation messages
                if ( ! data.success) {

                    // handle errors for usertype ---------------
                    if (data.errors.usertype) {
                        $('#usertype-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red select
                        $('#usertype-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.usertype + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our select
                    }

                    // handle errors for username ---------------
                    if (data.errors.username) {
                        $('#username-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#username-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.username + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for email ---------------
                    if (data.errors.email) {
                        $('#email-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#email-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for superhero alias ---------------
                    if (data.errors.password) {
                        $('#password-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#password-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.password + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                } else {

                    // ALL GOOD! just show the success message!
                    $('#ajax_form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');

                    // usually after form submission, you'll want to redirect
            // window.location = '/thank-you'; // redirect a user to another page
            alert('success'); // for now we'll just alert the user

                }
            })

            // using the fail promise callback
            .fail(function(data) {

                // show any errors
                // best to remove for production
                console.log(data);
            });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
</script>
```

And this is the php code:

```
    <?php
    include 'db.php';

     $errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
     $data           = array();      // array to pass back data

     //Searching for identical usernames
     $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM natspeaker WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'");
     $count = mysql_num_rows($search);

     $search2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nonnatspeaker WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'");
     $count2 = mysql_num_rows($search2);

     //Searching for identical emails
     $search3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM natspeaker WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'");
     $count3 = mysql_num_rows($search3);

     $search4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nonnatspeaker WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'");
     $count4 = mysql_num_rows($search4);

     //if( isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {
     if(isset($_POST)){
     //USERTYPE
     if(empty($_POST['usertype'])) { 
        $errors['usertype'] = "Please select if you are a native or a non-native speaker.<br>";
            }

     //USERNAME
     if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $errors['username'] = "Username is missing<br>";
            }else{//this "else" can be deleted

     /*this can be deleted in case of trouble*/if ( $count == 1 OR $count2 == 1) {
        $errors['username'] .= "Username already exists in our database. Choose another one<br>";
            }
            }//this bracket can be deleted.
     //EMAIL
     if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $errors['email'] = "Email is missing<br>";
            }else{//this "else" can be deleted

      if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $_POST['email'])) {
        $errors['email'] = "Invalid email<br>";
            }

       if ( $count3 == 1 OR $count4 == 1) {
        $errors['email'] = "Email already exists in our database. It seems you have an account yet.<br>";
            }
            }//this bracket can be deleted.

      //PASSWORD
      if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $errors['password'] = "Password is missing.<br>";
            }else{//this "else" can be deleted

      if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
        $errors['password'] = "Password too short<br>";
            }
            }//this bracket can be deleted.


        // return a response ===========================================================

       // if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
      if ( ! empty($errors)) {

        // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors; 
        //if(count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0){
        //This is for ajax requests:
        if( isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {
            //if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&  strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])== 'xmlhttprequest') {//something is wrong with this
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo "Ajax request is working.";
                echo json_encode($data);//now this iss working
                exit;
             }
           //This is when Javascript is turned off:
           echo "<br><br><br><center><div style=\"font-size:50;\">something is wrong or your Javascript is turned off. Ajax request is not working</div></center><br><br>";//delete
           echo $data;//delete
           //foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $key => $value){
          //echo "<li>" . $value . "</li>";
           //}
           //echo "</ul>";exit;
    }else{
    // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message

        // DO ALL YOUR FORM PROCESSING HERE
        // THIS CAN BE WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO (LOGIN, SAVE, UPDATE, WHATEVER)
if ( $_POST['usertype'] == "native speaker") { 
      $register = mysql_query("INSERT INTO natspeaker(username, email, password, time1, usertype)
       VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['password']."', now(), '".$_POST['usertype']."')") or die (mysql_error());
        }elseif ( $_POST['usertype'] == "non-native speaker"){
         $register = mysql_query("INSERT INTO nonnatspeaker(username, email, password, time1, usertype)
        VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['password']."', now(), '".$_POST['usertype']."')") or die (mysql_error());
         }

      // Let's mail the user!
      $subject = "Your Membership at Quintz!";
      $message = "Hi, ".$_POST['username'].",
      Thank you for registering at our website, http://www.quintz.club!

      You have registered as a ".$_POST['usertype'].".
      You are two steps away from logging in and accessing our exclusive members area.

      To activate your membership, please click here: http://www.quintz.club/activate.php

      Once you activate your membership, you will be able to login.

      And please do not forget to complete your profile.
      Thanks!
      The Webmaster

      This is an automated response, please do not reply!";

      mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, "From: Quintz Webmaster<support@quintz.club>\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

      // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Your account has been created successfully. Go to your email address and activate your account.';
        echo "successful register!";//delete
   }
}
//}
// return all our data to an AJAX call
//this works
//echo json_encode($data);//delete
?>
```

In sum, I just want to hinder the user from registering with a username that already exists in the database, or with an invalid email, or even missing information (blank fields), and just return those red notices in the same page join_form.php. The user can only go to the register2.php, if all information are approved to be passed to the database and finally exhibits the message "Successful register!" on this page and sends an email to the user. Just that!

Comment: Any error? On your page or in your console?

Comment: I'm using the fatcow server. No error in my page, just see the pictures, exactly as them.

Comment: How about in the console log (browser's Developer's Tool)?

Comment: OK. What is the link?

Comment: To see errors that might return from your Ajax. Just hit `F12` on your browser.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: form not defined. It shows very fast between the join_form.php and register2.php pages

Comment: In your ajax, try replacing the url data with `$("#ajax_form").attr('action'),` or with `"register2.php",`. Then get back to me if any other error occurs.

Comment: When I made these changes you recommended, the console points to the line where is event.preventDefault(); no Error, but all the same, it doesn't lead us to the page register2.php any more. Absolutely nothing happens when clicking the submit button. (Paused in debugger, if I'm not mistaken it may be the jQuery version, as it goes to jQuery original file, when clicking to play Paused in debugger successively, if at all you understand me).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go back to the beginning. Your HTML is clearly not on par and your PHP code is.. aged..

Go through what your code is doing, start with HTML, then do the form using jQuery where the output is just either `true` or the ID of the form field that failed, or something like it.

Just a few quick things;

- `title` goes inside `head`, not above it
- `mysql_query` is outdated, try using `mysqli_query` or the OOP variant of that
- Do counts when necessary, if the entire form is empty there's no reason to bug the mysql server
- Using OOP mysqli, you could just do `$s = $mysqli->query('SELECT [..]');` and then `if($s->num_rows > 0)` instead of making a new variable of the count, using that same way to verify a user does exist for logging in and then just using `$r = $s->fetch_assoc()` to get the user's details.
- Instead of grabbing the values, try writing them all to an array using `$('#form').serialize()` and then mosting that

In short, go back to the beginning, start over from scratch and use an updated tutorial.

Comment: My php version is 5.2. I don't know if it works with mysqli. The server I'm using is owned by (within) fatcow. I'm a newbie programmer and what does OOP mean?

Comment: If compiled with MySQLi it will work with MySQLi, so that depends on the host I guess. OOP is `object oriented programming`, which is an entirely different way to do things. Regardless, contact your host's support and see if they can update PHP, 5.2 has been too old for any kind of usage for a while now.

Comment: Where do I use $('#form').serialize()?

Comment: Instead of defining `formData` yourself you make it into `var formData = $('#ajax_form').serialize()`